# Cannot get my class to toggle

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I think my code is OK overall but i can't seem to get my jQuery to toggle classes.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
     $("#activity").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("activitymouseover");
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0gd6yeyj/ <-- Full code here

I'm using a script source: 
        src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js".

I get no change in class on a hover. I've tried addClass and removeClass also which  doesn't work either. When toggleClass is changed to another method such as 
    .hide();
The code works fine?

Comment: That should be working. Could you post any relevant html/css? It could be that on hover the element is changing in such a way that it loses hover and automatically fires again.

Comment: Your code is working fine. You can check this by changing the background-color of either #activity or .activitymouseover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that toggleClass remove and add more classes and your are using `id="activity"`.
Instead of id use class, check this:

```js
$(".activity").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("activitymouseover");
});
```

```css
.activity {
    width:980px;
    height:177px;
    color: #DCDCDC;
    background-color: #E8D700;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 64px;
}
.activitymouseover {
    width:980px;
    height:177px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #E8D700;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="activity">
    <div id="centeringdiv3">
        <h4>Activity</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! awesome. I thought I tried this already though. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("h4").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("activitymouseover");
});
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ox7px0ms/2/)**

Change selector from $("#activity") to $("h4")

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest instead of using jQuery to just use plain old CSS `:hover`:

```
#activity:hover {
  width:980px;
  height:177px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #E8D700;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0gd6yeyj/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This does fine. Although, I'm trying to stay organised by keeping all dynamic effects to jQuery code.